# Sort "use" keyword alphabetical, would save execution times and performance?

Tags: php, oop, php-5.6

I have being playing with OOP for a while and now phpStorm has this "Optimize imports" (Code > Optimize imports or CTRL+ALT+O) and what this does is sort alphabetically the use keywords as for example:

```
use A;
use D;
use C;
use B;
```

will turn into:

```
use A;
use B;
use C;
use D;
```

so, will that optimize some how my code execution? will this have some impacts on app performance?  or this is just a make up for better readability?

Comment: Readability is a good improvement. It saves human execution time :)

Comment: @Random yes I know but I am in a permanent discussion about sort or not to sort this with my boss ;) he said is not needed at all, I said is needed so I am trying to demonstrate if this will hit performance and execution or is just a makeup :D

Comment: When a bug will be spotted, he'll be interested to know the time you need to debug it... When you work on a app, readability is one of the most important things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of `use` statements will do nothing improve the performance of your code.

However, it does make for more human-digestible code.

With more than a handful of `use` statment, the readability is well worth the click freebie your IDE provides